# Namespace issue with period

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a class:

```
namespace FooIOS
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public static void doThis() {...}
    }
}
```

And this works:

```
using FooIOS;
namespace Sample.iOS
{
    public void method () {
        Foo.doThis();
    }
}
```

However, this does not work the same way when I change the namespace to insert a period:

```
namespace Foo.iOS
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public static void doThis() {...}
    }
}

using Foo.iOS;
namespace Sample.iOS
{
    public void method () {
        // Compilation error
        Foo.doThis();
        // Compilation error
        Foo.iOS.doThis()
        // This works but I can't have it that long and complicated (I'm writing an API call)
        Foo.iOS.Foo.doThis();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty inexperienced with C# and I'm wondering if there's any way to use the period in the namespace and not deal with the complicated call.

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace Foo.iOS
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public static void doThis() {...}
    }
}
```

Your namespace name is `Foo.iOS`, class name is `Foo`, static method name is `doThis()`. The fully qualified path to access that method is `NAMESPACE.CLASS.METHOD_NAME`, so it becomes:

```
Foo.iOS.Foo.doThis();
```

Here is nothing wrong with `C#`, but with the naming you use.

From this a couple of *suggestions*:

- try to no use `.` inside names of the namespace, as this introduces confusion
- try to not name namespace as the class inside it, as this introduces confusion.

> I'm pretty inexperienced with C# and I'm wondering if there's any way
>   to use the period in the namespace and not deal with the complicated
>   call.

Short answer is: name your namespaces, classes and member functions in a way, that it does not look complicated to you and to others.

**EDIT**

Consider that you can use also [Namespace Alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

For example:

```
using IOS = Foo.iOS; 
... 
IOS.Foo.doThis();
```

But as I said before, it's better to avoid `.` in namespace name at first place.

Comment: Also note that namespaces, classes, methods etc. are case sensitive. In OP's example the namespace is FooiOS but the using is FooIOS.

Comment: thanks for the answer. FooiOS vs FooIOS is just a typo.

Comment: Using `.` in your namespace is a perfectly valid way to create sub namespaces in larger projects. There's nothing inherently wrong with it. The .NET framework itself uses this construct quite religiously.

Answer (score 0):

Bring the `using Foo.iOS;` statement *inside* the `namespace Sample.iOS` namespace block, like shown below, then you will be able to call `doThis()` like in your 1st attempt `Foo.doThis();` that was previously giving you a compile error.

```
namespace Sample.iOS
{
    using Foo.iOS;

    public void method () {
        // this works
        Foo.doThis();
    }
}
```

**Related reading:** [Inside or Outside?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/25/inside-or-outside.aspx) by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) on MSDN.

#### Fully working Code sample:

Create a new Console App in Visual Studio, and then in the `Program.cs` class, delete all lines, paste the following, do a compile and then run.

```
using System;

namespace Foo.iOS
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public static void doThis() { Console.Write("Inside doThis");}
    }
}

namespace Sample.iOS
{
    using Foo.iOS;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            method();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void method () 
        {
            // works fine
            Foo.doThis();
        }
    } 
}
```